# Why can't I place blocks in Minecraft but I can break them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got Minecraft and I tried to place blocks by clicking the right button on the mouse. But instead of placing the block I was holding, it just destroyed the block I was looking at. This was in the creative gamemode, but I went into survival and it still didn't work. I went to settings and made sure the place/use item command was on button two. I reset all of the controls with the button. I am using a Mac. Please tell me what I can do to make it so I can place blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Try tapping two fingers,  that's the right click on most macbooks

Answer (score 0):

Many mac mouses do not have a right click button, instead two left click buttons. You will need to either get a new mouse that features a right click (any other mouse that isn't mac) or use Command+click instead of right clicking.